# SQL-Coding App for iPad

Tags: ipad, applications, software-recommendation, mysql

I'm searching for an iPad App where i can write and proceed SQL Statements.

I want to connect to my own Server.

Are there any Apps out there? I can only find MySQL Apps which are offering GUI-Editing of my Database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are quite a few SQL clients in the App Store, PostGres, MySql, Oracle, SqlServer

[Impathic](http://www.impathic.com/) make one for just about every database such as

- [SQL Server Mobile Database Client](http://itunes.apple.com/gb/app/sql-server-mobile-database/id387301608?mt=8)

I've not used these products myself, but they are known to be limited to creating queries graphically, you can't write your own SQL.

The higher end versions, do allow you greater flexibility and the iPad apps are pretty good, however and this is a caveat, if you run SQL that returns lots of data, the query runs slowly since the amount of data being returned can be large and the handling of the large amount of data is limited by the iOS devices memory.  Write more concise SQL to return only the data you need and the apps run fine.

Comment: So there aren't any apps, or what do you mean with "higher end versions"?

Comment: there are many apps, the example I gave comes in two flavours one is cheaper and has less features, the other is more expensive and has more features.  Unless you supply the database type you want to connect to, then  honestly, I cant winnow it down any further than Google can as in Google "iPad sql client"

Answer (score -2):

I don't believe Apple allows such apps because they execute code. I would look on the Apple Developer pages for more info.

Comment: I believe the code execution restrictions are in reference to code that is executed on the device.  It looks like the question is asking if there is a way to connect to a remote server and perform SQL operations against the remote server's database.  This is analogous to having an app allowing SSH access to a server and performing actions on the remote server.  There are many of these apps in the App Store (Prompt, iSSH, and many remote management apps).